# How to delete data on a server via an API and DELETE request in httr

Tags: r, api, httr, http-delete

I'm new to this whole API thing and certainly don't understand the full logic, but hope you can help me out here.

Please note that I can only provide a generic example without a reproducible example since the site I want to access requires a paid login.

What I want to do is to delete certain values from a data column on the server.

The data on the server is a survey with each column representing a survey question. I now want to delete from the column "xyz" the case with a value of "abc".

The help page from said website provides the following help on how to delete data:

http://release.decipherinc.com/s/local/beacon.html#data-input-and-output-modify-data-delete

And this is how I tried to achieve deleting the data:

```
library(httr)
library(tidyverse)
library(jsonlite)

my_data <- data.frame(xyz = c("abc", "def", "ghi"))
todelete <- my_data %>%
  filter(xyz == "abc")

my_platform_key <- "testkey"

# small function for the URL request
api_delete <- function(path)
{
  url <- paste0("release.decipherinc.com/api/v1/", path)
  add_headers(my_platform_key)
  DELETE(url, add_headers('x-apikey' = my_platform_key))
}

delete_request <- api_delete("surveys/MYSURVEY/data/edit?mode=delete&key=xyz&data=todelete")
```

I *guess* the problem might be with how I specify the `data` parameter. The help page says it needs to be an array, but not sure if simply passing a data frame is sufficient.

When I run this code followed up by: `content(delete_request, encoding = "UTF-8")` the response code is 400, so indicating that it didn't work (obviously):

> data: expected an array, not string

What do I need to change in my code so that it will work?

**Update**

Digging deeper into the topic I found some additional information, but it still doesn't work. According to some other SO post, I tried the following:

```
library(jsonlite)
library(httr)
args <- list(key = unbox("xyz"),
             data = todelete,
             mode = unbox("delete"))

body <- toJSON(args)

DELETE(url         = "release.decipherinc.com/api/v1/surveys/MYSURVEY/data/edit",
       add_headers('x-apikey' = my_platform_key),
       body = body,
       encode = "json")
```

I checked the content of `body` and it looks exactly how it is described in the linked documentation, but it still doesn't work:

```
{"key":"xyz","data":[{"xyz":"abc"}],"mode":"delete"}
```

And the server response is:

```
Response [...URL...]
  Date: 2020-04-04 17:50
  Status: 400
  Content-Type: application/json
  Size: 72 B
{
 "$error": "missing argument 'data'",
 "$code": 400,
 "extra": null
}
```

Comment: I checked the document through the link, and I saw it sends the data in  the body as an array, not request/path parameter/variable as a string, have you tried the same way it sent the data? is there add_body like method you can call?

Comment: No, I thought I can just use something similar as getting the data. To be honest, I don‘t really know how I could delete the data in „the same way it sent the data“. Not sure what you with that. In terms of add_body, the httr function DELETE has a body parameter, I can check it, but I‘m relatively sure I don‘t understand (yet) how.

Comment: updated my post with some additional things I tried (but didn't work).

Answer (score 0):

OK, I figured it out on my own with a lot of trial and error. I was missing one particular parameter in my function, i.e. content_type. The code below works:

```
library(httr)
library(tidyverse)
library(jsonlite)

my_data <- data.frame(xyz = c("abc", "def", "ghi"))

todelete <- my_data %>%
  filter(xyz == "abc")

my_platform_key <- "testkey"

args <- list(key = unbox("xyz"),
             data = todelete,
             mode = unbox("delete"))

body <- toJSON(args)

DELETE(url         = "release.decipherinc.com/api/v1/surveys/MYSURVEY/data/edit",
       add_headers('x-apikey' = my_platform_key),
       content_type("application/json"),
       body = body,
       encode = "json")
```